# Compiling custom kernel for HP Thin client and creating bootable ISO with grub

Tags: c, osdev, grub, thin-client

I made simple OS with one really nice library, I compiled everything, reallocated (I want) and finaly created kernel. I successfully ran it on `qemu-system-i386`. Plus created ISO with grub and boot it via virtualbox. Everything worked, output was OK.

So, I copied it to usb (`dd if=bin/os.iso of=/dev/sdd1`) and put into my `HP Thin Client t5550/t5565/t5570`. But after start, I just saw "GRUB ".

I tried also power pc compiler (maybe I went more far away, don't know why I remembered on it) downloaded from http://wiki.osdev.org/GCC_Cross-Compiler#Prebuilt_Toolchains (For Linux x86_64 host; powerpc-elf 4.9.1 target). Compiled, copied to usb and got the same result.

What compiler should I use to compile for HP Thin clients? I want to (learn to) develop simple kernel for it.

PS: I am on ubuntu amd64, kernel was written in C + asm, but I removed the assembly version (or, what output type should I use for `nasm` compiler?)

**EDIT**

It looks like grub bug/error.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwwS9.png

I have got this result on my laptop & thin client. Don't know why, on virtual box it works. Or, am I copying the iso to the usb bad way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command for copying was invalid, resp. target output was invalid. Valid command is - `dd if=bin/os.iso of=/dev/sdd` **copy the iso direct to disk, not to partition (no digits)**. Working well!